# Categories where every morphism is a monomorphism

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

What is the name given to categories where every morphism is a monomorphism?  Where have these been studied?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These categories are closely related to preorder categories (a.k.a. thin categories) and preordered groupoids:

**Proposition.**
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category.
The following are equivalent:

- Every morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ is a monomorphism.
- For every object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, the slice $\mathcal{C}_{/ X}$ is a preorder category.
- There exists a preorder category $\mathcal{D}$ and a surjective discrete fibration $P : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$.
- (Assuming $\mathcal{C}$ is small.) The presheaf topos $[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is an étendue, i.e. there exists a presheaf $D : \mathcal{C}^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Set}$ such that the unique morphism $D \to 1$ is an epimorphism and the slice $[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]_{/ D}$ is a localic topos.
- $\mathcal{C}$ is the codescent category of a preordered groupoid whose domain and codomain maps are discrete fibrations, i.e. we have a codescent diagram in $\textbf{Cat}$ of the form below,
  $$\mathcal{G}_2 \mathrel{\begin{array}{c} \rightarrow \\ \rightarrow \\ \rightarrow \end{array}} \mathcal{G}_1 \mathrel{\begin{array}{c} \rightarrow \\ \leftarrow \\ \rightarrow \end{array}} \mathcal{G}_0 \to \mathcal{C}$$
  where $\mathcal{G}_2$, $\mathcal{G}_1$, and $\mathcal{G}_0$ are preorder categories, $\mathcal{G}_1 \rightrightarrows \mathcal{G}_0$ are discrete fibrations, and the $\mathcal{G}_\bullet$ comprise a groupoid object.

Étendues were originally defined in [SGA4, Exposé IV, Exercice 9.8.2].
The connection with groupoids was already noted then, but was generalised (to non-étendues) by various authors, particularly Joyal and Tierney [*An extension of the Galois theory of Grothendieck*].

Answer (score 7):

Such categories are called [left-cancellative](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cancellative+category) (see the link for references). A one-object left-cancellative category is a [left-cancellative monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup).

Answer (score 3):

One example I can think of is the category $FI$, the category of finite sets (objects) and injections (arrows). This category is very important in representation theory wherein people study $FI$-modules over a ring (or more generally, over a small preadditive category). The notion of $FI$-modules was first introduced by T.Church, J. Eilenberg and B. Farb to obtain a new approach to the theory of stability of representations of $S_n$.